# How to connect to database from script in /lib dir?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I have a script in `lib` directory and I need to fetch some data.

```
require 'active_record'

Article.each do ...
```

When I try this, I got this error message:

```
file.rb:3:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Article (NameError)
```

How can I load data from Rails database and display them in a raw ruby script?

Comment: is it a task?  or just a script.  Making it a task, you just make it depend on environment ` task :do_cool_stuff => :environment do`, for example.  If a standalone script, you need to include the rails environment,  take a look at bin/rails or the like for an idea how to do that (I like tasks as they are way easier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the command `rails runner lib/your_script.rb`, from the Rails application root directory, to execute your script. It will execute the script after loading the Rails environment, so in the script you have full access to your models.

Answer (score 1):

In your script you should add adapter, something like this:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'sqlite3'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
   :adapter => 'sqlite3',
   :database => 'db/yourDb.db'
)
```

And model(s), like this:

```
require_relative 'path to your model(s) file(s)'
```

Answer (score 0):

see rails doc for method 'establish_connection'

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-establish_connection

Answer (score -1):

This will help you to connect your db with active record:
http://www.runtime-era.com/2012/11/dynamic-activerecord-database.html